# Setting background color for LI element

Tags: html, css

Referencing this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jeljeljel/SXajC/7/)

I want to color the background of the LI being hovered over.  However it seems to set the class on the entire set of LI elements (not just the hovered one).

Can someone see what the issue is here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just do this:

```
.parentSelectorBox li:hover 
{
    background-color:red;
}​
```

you don't need js to achieve hover effect. CSS will be fine.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you anchor your JS to the whole list.

See [that](http://jsfiddle.net/SXajC/18/).

I don't remove all JQuery stuff, but only what set to hover your li class.
I suggest to remove JS that know is useless

Comment: Oops.  Yes, I see the issue now.